# How to include WordPress functions in custom .php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, include

**How can I include WordPress functions in a custom .php file?**

In detail: I have a directory under my theme (Constructor) named reports. These contain .php files that generate reports from data from the site with DOMPDF for downloading. For these I would like to use functions that the WordPress engine provides, for example `get_the_author_meta( 'user_firstname', $user_id )`. If I use these i get (naturally) the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_author_meta() in ROOT/public_html/wp-content/themes/constructor/reports/testreport.php on line 15

I was lead to believe that I need to include wp-blog-header.php . I use `require_once("../../../../wp-blog-header.php");` . With this I get the following 404 error:

> No webpage was found for the web address: ROOT/wp-content/themes/constructor/reports/testreport.php

(The require points to the correct path. If I fiddle with it, I get Warning: require_once(../../../wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream... So the path must be correct.)

Is there something I overlook? Why can't I include this wp file? What is the correct method to include the wp functions?

Thanks for the help, Sziro

Comment: For Gutenberg users: https://wpza.net/including-wordpress-functions-in-a-custom-php-file/

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Try this instead:

```
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
```

Comment: this is fine solution but that will load all wp site with all installed plugins and themes ... this violation of yagni principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it

Comment: This may be true if he was loading a file INSIDE of Wordpress but if you read the original question he was asking how to load it from an external php file.

Comment: so, if it isn't Yagni... what should it be?

Comment: require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-load.php"); is easier than all the ../'s

Comment: Cleaner: `require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');`

Comment: `$_SERVER` may not be defined via cli, use `__DIR__ . '/path/to/wp-load,php';`

Comment: I'm not sure how old this post is, but for my installation on wordpress 4 and 5 it's only three `../` before the file. ie: `../../../wp-load.php`

Comment: Yea this was from me almost 6 years ago :)

Answer (score 32):

To use wp functions in custom .php files, you must include `wp-load.php` in your file.
You can do so by adding the following line:

```
require_once(PATH_TO.'/wp-load.php');
```

If WordPress is in the document root add instead:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

Comment: WordPress is not necessarily in the document root.

Comment: Also you need to rtrim document_root for forward slashes

Answer (score 4):

Well if someone has newer PHP versions installed (ver >= 5.5.x) then they can also try the below code in the root script in WordPress website directory itself:

```
<?php
define("WP_ROOT", __DIR__);
define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require_once WP_ROOT . DS . "wp-load.php";
```

Or

```
<?php
define("WP_ROOT", __DIR__);
define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require_once WP_ROOT . DS . "wp-blog-header.php";
```

I guess this is a more direct and clean approach and doesn't involve manually adding slashes and changing diretories by `..`.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/options.php');
```

This is better way to include a file in WordPress.

Comment: He wasn't asking how to include a file in Wordpress.  He wanted to load Wordpress from an external PHP file.  Your solution would not work.

Comment: He's aware of that I'm sure. He's adding to the discussion. Now I'm going to use this method + wp-load.php.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I use this method to load WordPress environment outside WordPress.

```
  if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php')) {

      /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
      require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

External files can easily access the WordPress functions. You just need to include the file `wp-load.php` in your external file.
The `wp-load.php` file is located in root of your WordPress installation.
Example: Suppose your file is `test.php` located at root directory of WordPress installation.

```
<?php
require_once('wp-load.php');
// Your custom code
?>
```

Source: [How to access WordPress functions in external file](https://webolute.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-access-wordpress-functions-in-external-file)

Answer (score 0):

Use `chdir` PHP function to change working directory.

It's need to prevent possible issues like `Class not found` exceptions.

```php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

chdir($root);

require_once($root . '/wp-load.php');
```