# Loading wp-load.php using require_once causes error in pdf generation using DomPDF

Tags: wordpress, dompdf

I have an external php file that contains the code to generate pdf using DOMPDF. I needed to access WordPress built-in functions in that file.
So, by following this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file), I included the following line:

```
require_once(plugins_url().'/../../wp-load.php');
```

Now, I am able to call WP functions, but the generated pdf is broken i.e I get "error trying to open the pdf..".

If I comment out the require_once line, the pdf comes out fine. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Adding this information, in case someone might find it useful. If I open the generated report in Notepad++ It contains all php comments of my file in it, while a normal report (the one generated without putting wp-load) does not contain those comments.

Comment: The actual PHP code, or just random comments? If the PDF is being produced then you probably have output buffering enabled. This can cause problems when parsing a file because some output (PHP notices, for example) can get caught in the output stream before dompdf creates the PDF.

Comment: @BrianS It is the actual php comments.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my problem. What I was doing was this: I was fetching contents from a POST variable, and appending its content into the dompdf html. The problem, was I was including the wp-load.php file before fetching the POST variables. Hence my post variables were getting garbled, I suppose. Now, I changed the order i.e I read all the POST variables, saved them into other variables and then did include wp-load.php. Everything worked smooth then. Not sure whether this is the correct way, but it worked for me. Thanks for everyones help. I am marking this thread as solved