# Calling functions of a wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Do they know if there is a way to call a Wordpress functions and functions of some plugins thereof, from a different directory it was installed Wordpress, but all on the same server?

Thank you! :)

Comment: you need to use `include` or `require` to fetch those files, where these functions are, but do not do this. this is a really bad practice.

Comment: I also think it is a bad practice, maybe use admin-ajax.php?action= and file_get_contents with stream_context_create, but I think that too it is a bad practice, because the calls are in the same server

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is this piece of code:

```
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
```

Keep in mind that not all WP installations have the same folder structure, the example above starts from a folder inside the theme directory, so you might need to add or remove "../".

This is, however, not a very good practice because it overwrites WP core functions.

Also, this question was already asked before many times, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file).