# Wordpress style.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

Can't see to update my style.php file with the following

Here is my style.php coding..

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$fontColor = "#<?php echo get_option('mwg_font_paragraph'); ?>";
?>

#content p {
color: <?php echo $fontColor; ?>;
}
```

If clear out that link and manually enter a color, it works fine:

```
$fontColor = "#FF0000";
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: You can't do PHP inside PHP like that. `$fontColor = "#" . get_option('mwg_font_paragraph');` or `color: #<?php echo get_option('mwg_font_paragraph'); ?>;` - either one will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As Nirpendra stated, you're using PHP inside PHP. Your code should look like this instead:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$fontColor = "#" . get_option('mwg_font_paragraph');
?>

#content p {
color: <?php echo $fontColor; ?>;
}
```

When you want to concatenate (join) multiple values together in PHP, whether they be strings, function calls, variables or something else, you need to use the `.` to join them, rather than nest additional PHP tags.

All the `<?php ... ?>` tags do is indicate what code PHP should parse, and when you're inside those tags, it's already parsing what you write.

Comment: First - thanks for helping out on this one..  I tried the coding you recommended, but it's still adjusting the font color based on the get_option..  like I said if I just put in the font color - it works, but for some reason it's not pulling the information from the theme option. I've even double checked the option name..

Comment: Ohh, got ya. It's most likely because this file isn't part of the Wordpress ecosystem. Can you see any errors when you visit it directly? Try doing what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15306647/1982136) says - you may need to adjust the path depending on how your theme is set up.

Comment: How did you go with this @user3096500?

Answer (score 0):

You are using nested php inside php in your first line.