# Link a PHP site from root directory (WordPress template)

Tags: php, wordpress, require

I want to link a static PHP site from a folder in my root directory in the WordPress template file.

I tried using:

```
<?php require_once (get_bloginfo('url') . '/programm/loginform.php'); ?>
```

but it does not work.

I am trying to connect a:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> /programm/loginform.php" ?>
```

and a:

```
<?php require 'loginform.php'?>
```

Comment: It won't work because it doesn't know about WordPress unless you include the libraries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include Wordpress functions in custom .php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file)

Comment: I have tried it and unfortunately it did not work
loginform.php is a static php file which i want to include into the index page of the cms 

i got these error messages 
(next comment

Comment: Warning: require_once(../../../../loginform.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp0\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wpsteli1\header.php on line 60

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../../../loginform.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes') in C:\xampp0\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wpsteli1\header.php on line 60