# Custom form and action attribute in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, forms

I've fallen in the (unknown to me) abyss of the custom forms and custom form handlers in wordpress. 
I just need a working contact form without the need of installing any plugin. 
I would normally do this with the $_SESSION superglobal (to pass error and success messages) and a post-redirect-get pattern (avoiding double sends with page reloads). The code would look like this

```
<form class="di-contact" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/contact.php" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto">
<h3 id="titulo-single"><?php the_title() ?></h3>
<label for="di-name"><?php _e('Name', 'di-news-blog'); ?>:</label>
<input class="uk-input" type="text" id="di-name"  name="di-name"><br>
<label for="di-email"><?php _e('E-mail', 'di-news-blog'); ?>:</label>
<input class="uk-input" type="email" id="di-email"  name="di-email"><br>
<label for="di-message"><?php _e('Message', 'di-news-blog'); ?>:</label>
<textarea class="uk-textarea" id="di-message"  name="di-message"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="di-submit" value="<?php _e('Submit', 'di-news-blog'); ?>">
</form>
```

Then i would code something like this in contact.php:

```
<?php
////////////////////   MAIL PROPERTIES      ///////////////////

$to = get_option('admin_email');
$from = htmlentities($_POST['di-email']);   
$subject = __('Message from ','di-news-blog'). get_bloginfo('blogname');

////////////////////////   HEADERS   ////////////////////////

$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

////////////////////////   MESSAGE  ////////////////////////

$message = '<p>You got a message from <strong>'  . 
htmlentities($_POST['di-name']) . '</strong><p/>';
$message .= '<p><strong>Email:</strong> ' . $from . '</p>';
$message .= '<strong>Message:</strong><br/>' . 
htmlentities($_POST['di-message']);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ( isset( $_POST['di-submit'] ) ) {
if (  ! empty( $_POST['di-email'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['di-email'] ) ||  ! empty( $_POST['di-message'] ) ) {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    $_SESSION['success'] = '<p class="success">' . __('Message sent succesfully', 'di-news-blog') . '</p>';

    wp_redirect(get_template_directory_uri() . '/contact'); exit;
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = '<p class="failed">' . __('Please enter all the requested data and try again', 'di-news-blog') . '</p>';

   wp_redirect(get_template_directory_uri() . '/contact'); exit;
  }
}
```

But nooby me, i just found out wordpress functions like `get_option()` or `__('','')` won't work in a page like contact.php, and also the $_SESSION superglobal, i was told i could make it work with something like that in the `functions.php` file:

```
// SESSIONS //////
function register_my_session(){
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session', 1);

function cyb_session_start() {
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function cyb_session_end() {
    session_destroy();
}

add_action( 'init', 'cyb_session_start', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'cyb_session_end' );
add_action( 'wp_login', 'cyb_session_end' );
```

which didn't work.
Sorry my ignorance, but i couldn't find documentation (that i understand, not a nijna php dev) on how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would send the form POST back to `/contact` (the contact form page) and handle the form send from there.

To keep the template clean I'd normally create a function in `functions.php` which you can then call from the template, and I'd create a specific contact page template in the theme called `page-contact.php` (which will automatically be used for the page with the slug `contact`). This would be the only template that needs to call the contact form handler function.

You can actually include Wordpress within your own custom (non-template) files so that you can use wordpress functions, but I don't think it's necessary for what you're trying to do.

A very minimal example:

**page-contact.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php contact_form_handler(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<?php include_once 'templates/no-posts-found.php'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function contact_form_handler() {

  /* If this is a postback, handle the contact form */
  if(isset($_POST['message'])) {

    //Try to send the message and set $successful to true or false

    echo ($successful ? "Message sent!" : "An error occurred");

  } 

  /* Otherwise display the form itself */
  else {
    include_once 'templates/contact-form.php';
  }
}
```

**templates/contact-form.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="/contact">
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try it in a minute and log back. Just for the curiosity, how can you  include Wordpress within your own custom (non-template) files so that you can use wordpress functions??

Comment: Looks like the simplest way is including wp-load.php from the wordpress core directory. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file

I can't say I know what security or performance implications that may have though.