# wp functions not being recognized in cron job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

**Setting:**

I have a wordpress site but disabled `wp_cron` to have the full control of cron.

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

In `crontab -e`, I have following cron job:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/cron/mycron.php init >> /var/log/error.log 2>&1
```

The `mycron.php` has a simple function

```
if (!empty($argv[1])) {        
    switch ($argv[1]){
    case 'init':
        cron_test();
        break;
    }
}
function cron_test() {
    $time = date(DATE_RFC822, time());
    write_log("Start:" . $time);   //outputs debug to my own log file   
};

function write_log($log){
    if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
        if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
            write_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
        } else {
            write_log( $log );
        }
    }
};
```

Note that I declared the `mycron.php` in `functions.php` for wp:

```
require_once('parts/mycron.php');
```

**Error log:**

In my `error.log` for the cron, I have the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant WP_DEBUG - assumed 'WP_DEBUG'
```

So, I am guessing there is some sort of disconnection between cron and wp, which is my best guess.

**What I am trying to do:**

The `mycron.php` will have many wordpress functions that I would need. How do I make the cron to recognize the `wp function` such as `WP_DEBUG`?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to load Wordpress functions manually, to use them in a custom script.

```
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
```

Also answered in depth here,

[How to include Wordpress functions in custom .php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file)

Comment: You could also mark this as an answer, if it helped you.