# how do you get current userid in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi have a simple php file in my wordpress site, where I need the current userid
I have tried the following, but keep getting

Call to undefined function get_current_user_id()

```
<?php 
   include '../../mydbfile.php';
   global $wpdb;
   // get current user ID, with default value, if empty
   $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
   error_log('current_user_id '.$current_user_id);
```

Comment: are you calling wp-load.php anywhere?

Comment: where would I put it in the example above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file

Comment: Thanks Howard E.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include wp-load.php to call the global $wpdb

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;
// get current user ID, with default value, if empty
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
error_log('current_user_id '.$current_user_id);
```

This has been tested and works.