# Access variables or functions from other scripts in cron job via cPanel

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cpanel

**Background**

Hi,

I am new to cron jobs and I am trying to set up a test one just to see how they work. I created it in cPanel like this:

```
wget -O - -q https://website.com/staging/wp-content/themes/AT103/test-cron.php
```

My file is pretty simple so far:

```
<?php

$email_to = "info@domain.com";   
$title = "Test title";    
$body = "Test body";

mail($email_to, $title, $body);

?>
```

All works fine here, I recieve the email every interval that my cron job runs.

**What I want**

On my site people can put up ads/listings to sell their stuff. In the cron job I want to go through all listings and email the buyers and sellers for the ones that has expired. As a first step in this I need to access the variables on my website, e.g. a listing object which is put in a variable like $post. Or through a function which returns the stuff I want if easier.

**What I tried**

I tried to access a random file and its functions by using lots of different code examples found online. The file is in the same folder as my test-cron.php. Here are a few things I tried to put at the top of test-cron.php (one at a time, not all at once):

```
require '/functions.php';    
require 'https://website.com/staging/wp-content/themes/AT103/functions.php';
require '/home3/username/public_html/staging/wp-content/themes/AT103/functions.php';
```

This all resulted in the same thing, I did not get an email anymore. So I assume there is some sort of error with the lines? I also tried with require_once() with the same result.

**Questions**

1. How do I access other scripts ("live" variables or functions) in my folder hierarchy through a cron job?
2. If it is not possible for some reason, can I instead access my database information somehow?

Comment: Why the -1? What is wrong with this question now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file to be required/included, is in the same folder as the running script you would use one of the following:

- `require 'functions.php';` no leading slash tells it to look in the include path, then in the current directory.
- `require './functions.php';` (better) the `./` explicitly says look in the current directory.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

**EDIT:**
*I just realized I did not address the fact that you are using cron and that's because ...*

**You are sill running PHP, cronjob or not makes no difference it still works the same**!
However, it can be more difficult to debug on a production server. If you want to see exactly what's happening when the script fails then you can wrap it in a `try` block, `catch` and send the error to your email, or output the error and view it in the browser.
I know on Bluehost shared-hosting, if any of my cronjobs produce any output it will be automatically sent to me via email. I use the format below, and always get an email telling me when & why it happened. While developing you can simply navigate to your `test-cron.php` in the browser.

```php
<?php
try {
    require './functions.php';
    /* 
    all of your logic 
    */

} catch (Error $e) {
    echo "Caught Error: \n" . $e;
}
```

Comment: It seems there is an error in functions.php, which only has one line: if(!defined('THEME_VERSION') ){ include("framework/_config.php"); }. Call to undefined function get_option(). Not sure if this is due to it being a cron job or something?

Comment: OK, that is a WordPress issue, apparently you need to require wp-load.php look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15304926/6127393

Comment: Thank you, the script now runs without errors. Thank you so much :)

Comment: https://zeropointdevelopment.com/how-to-use-wordpress-functions-in-a-non-wordpress-custom-php-file-wpquickies/