# Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null and Warning: Attempt to read property "prefix" on null

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am developing a plugin for wordpress and I need to be able to have a function in the admin panel where you click import prices and it activates a script and imports the file into the database.

However, I had it working just for importing into a txt file, wheni modified that code to import into a database I always seem to get an error around the following:

> Full Response: 
> **Warning**:  Attempt to read property "prefix" on null in **D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\twentyi-api-integration\dashboard\function\class-twentyi-api-integration-domain-pricing.php** on line **80**
>
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\twentyi-api-integration\dashboard\function\class-twentyi-api-integration-domain-pricing.php:84
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\twentyi-api-integration\dashboard\function\class-twentyi-api-integration-domain-pricing.php(132): TwentyiApiIntegrationDomainPricing->importPricesIntoDatabase(Array)
> #1 {main}
> thrown in **D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\twentyi-api-integration\dashboard\function\class-twentyi-api-integration-domain-pricing.php** on line **84**

I have this code so far:

Form:

```
<?php
// CSRF token generation
if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}
?>

<div class="domain-wrap column-1">
    <!-- Import Form -->
    <div class="domain-inner-column-1">
        <h2 class="get-domain-pricing-head">Import Domain Pricing into Database</h2>
        <p class="get-domain-pricing-text">
            Before you can use the integration for domain searching and results, you need to import the values into the database from the 20i servers.
        </p>
        <form class="get-domain-pricing-form" id="get-domain-pricing-form" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
            <!-- markup -->
            <label for="domain-markup">Custom Markup (%)</label>
            <select id="domain-markup" name="domain-markup">
                <?php
                // Populate the dropdown with numbers in increments of 5 from 0 to 100
                for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i += 5) {
                    echo "<option value='$i'>$i%</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <!-- Add CSRF token as a hidden input -->
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf_token']; ?>">
            <!-- submit button -->
            <button type="submit" id="get-domain-pricing-submit">Import Domain Pricing</button>
            <div id="get-domain-pricing-response"></div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Update Form -->
    <div class="domain-inner-column-2">
        <h2 class="update-domain-pricing-head">Update Domain Pricing into Database</h2>
        <p class="update-domain-pricing-text">
            If you notice that the prices are wrong, you may need to update the values again into the database from the 20i servers.
        </p>
        <form class="update-domain-pricing-form" id="update-domain-pricing-form" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
            <!-- markup -->
            <label for="domain-markup-update">Custom Markup (%)</label>
            <select id="domain-markup-update" name="domain-markup-update">
                <?php
                // Populate the dropdown with numbers in increments of 5 from 0 to 100
                for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i += 5) {
                    echo "<option value='$i'>$i%</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>

            <!-- Add CSRF token as a hidden input -->
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf_token']; ?>">
            <!-- submit button -->
            <button type="submit" id="update-domain-pricing-submit">Update Domain Pricing</button>
            <div id="update-domain-pricing-response"></div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Second column content goes here -->
    <div class="domain-wrap column-2">
      <p class="test">hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Ensure that $wpdb is properly initialized in your WordPress environment
global $wpdb;

class TwentyiApiIntegrationDomainPricing {
    private $wpdb;

    public function __construct($wpdb) {
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
    }

    public function fetchPrices() {
        try {
            // Validate and sanitize the URL
            $registerUrl = filter_var('https://my.20i.com/a/product/domain/new', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
            if ($registerUrl === false) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid registration URL.');
            }

            // Fetch registration prices
            $registerJson = file_get_contents($registerUrl);
            $regDecode = json_decode($registerJson, true);

            if ($regDecode === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
                throw new Exception('Error parsing JSON data for registration prices.');
            }

            $extensionData = [];

            foreach ($regDecode as $tldKey => $tldParts) {
                // Check if 'yearly' is set in the pricing structure
                $yearlyData = isset($tldParts['pricing']['card']['yearly']) ? $tldParts['pricing']['card']['yearly'] : null;

                $extensionData[$tldKey] = [
                    'tld' => $tldKey,
                    'registrationPrice' => isset($yearlyData['non_reseller']['purchase']) ? $yearlyData['non_reseller']['purchase'] : 0,
                    'renewalPrice' => isset($yearlyData['non_reseller']['purchase']) ? $yearlyData['non_reseller']['purchase'] : 0,
                    'currencyCode' => "GBP",
                    'minPeriod' => 1,
                    'maxPeriod' => 9
                ];
            }

            // Validate and sanitize the URL
            $transferUrl = filter_var('https://my.20i.com/a/product/domain/transfer', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
            if ($transferUrl === false) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid transfer URL.');
            }

            // Fetch transfer prices
            $xferJson = file_get_contents($transferUrl);
            $xferDecode = json_decode($xferJson, true);

            foreach ($xferDecode as $tldKey => $tldParts) {
                $extensionData[$tldKey]['transferPrice'] = isset($tldParts['pricing']['card']['yearly']['non_reseller']['purchase']) ? $tldParts['pricing']['card']['yearly']['non_reseller']['purchase'] : 0;
            }

            return $extensionData;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Handle the exception, log or return an error response
            $response = array(
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
            return;
        }
    }

    public function importPricesIntoDatabase($extensionData) {
        try {
            if (!is_array($extensionData) || empty($extensionData)) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid extension data.');
            }

            // Define the table name
            $tablename = $this->wpdb->prefix . 'tiapi_domain_pricing';

            foreach ($extensionData as $data) {
                // Insert data into the database
                $this->wpdb->insert(
                    $tablename,
                    array(
                        'tld'                     => $data['tld'],
                        'registration_price'      => $data['registrationPrice'],
                        'renewal_price'           => $data['renewalPrice'],
                        'transfer_price'          => $data['transferPrice'],
                        'currency_code'           => $data['currencyCode'],
                        'min_period'              => $data['minPeriod'],
                        'max_period'              => $data['maxPeriod'],
                    ),
                    array(
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                    )
                );
            }

            // Output JSON response for success
            $response = array(
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Domain pricing data has been successfully imported into the WordPress database.'
            );

            echo json_encode($response);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Handle the exception, log or return an error response
            $response = array(
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}

// Example usage
$twentyiApiIntegration = new TwentyiApiIntegrationDomainPricing($wpdb);

// Fetch prices
$extensionData = $twentyiApiIntegration->fetchPrices();

// Import prices into the WordPress database
$twentyiApiIntegration->importPricesIntoDatabase($extensionData);
?>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const domainPricingForm = document.getElementById('get-domain-pricing-form');
  const updateDomainPricingForm = document.getElementById('update-domain-pricing-form');
  const domainPricingURL = '/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/twentyi-api-integration/dashboard/function/class-twentyi-api-integration-domain-pricing.php';

  if (domainPricingForm) {
    domainPricingForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const markup = document.getElementById('domain-markup').value;

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('formId', 'get-domain-pricing-form');
      formData.append('markup', markup);

      makeFetchRequest(domainPricingURL, formData, 'get-domain-pricing-response');
    });
  }
 
  if (updateDomainPricingForm) {
    updateDomainPricingForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const markupUpdate = document.getElementById('domain-markup-update').value;

      const formDataUpdate = new FormData();
      formDataUpdate.append('formId', 'update-domain-pricing-form');
      formDataUpdate.append('markup', markupUpdate);

      makeFetchRequest(domainPricingURL, formDataUpdate, 'update-domain-pricing-response');
    });
  }

  function makeFetchRequest(url, data, responseElementId) {
    console.log('URL:', url);
    console.log('FormData:', data);
  
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Response Status:', response.status);
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(text => {
      console.log('Full Response:', text);
  
      try {
        const result = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log('Parsed Response:', result);
  
        // Your existing code for handling the parsed JSON response
        if (result.success) {
          document.getElementById(responseElementId).innerHTML = '<div style="color:green;">Domain pricing imported successfully.</div>';
        } else {
          document.getElementById(responseElementId).innerHTML = '<div style="color:red;">' + result.error + '</div>';
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('JSON Parse Error:', error);
        document.getElementById(responseElementId).innerHTML = '<div style="color:red;">Error parsing JSON response.</div>';
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Fetch Error:', error);
      document.getElementById(responseElementId).innerHTML = '<div style="color:red;">Error fetching data from the server.</div>';
    });
  }  
});
```

I have tried multiple iterations and even consulted AI to no avail.

I have tried

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
```

But this caused further errors.

Comment: "Ensure that $wpdb is properly initialized in your WordPress environment" -- apparently it's not. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15306647/482864 I wouldn't count on it containing $wpdb at that point either, insert an `add_action( 'init' ...` there to make sure the core is loaded by the time you interact with the database.